Multiple API requests made when trying to async submit a form from a child component
I'm new to React. I've built an application which supports a user searching for a substance by an identifier called a CAS Number. It makes a single API request per search term to get the data and stores any previous searches in Local Storage.
The app is working - it's possible to submit a search term (CAS), get data back from the API, and see previous searches.
I'm trying to build a feature that allows a user to re-submit a previous search by clicking on some text which shows the CAS they entered. This data comes from Local Storage and is output in the UI like so:

As an example if the user clicked on "117-81-7" it would

Populate the search form with "117-81-7".
Submit the form, therefore making another API request for the data. As per the initial search it should only make a single request when this happens.

Part 1 works, but I can't seem to implement part 2. I've read How to submit form from a button outside that component in React?. But the answer says

notify child component about button click in the parent.

which is the same as what I'm trying to do, with a minor difference that it's an anchor rather than a button the user clicks.
My app has just 2 components. One is the search form and the other is the Previous Searches history (shown on the screenshot earlier).
The code looks like this.
// App.jsx
return (
    <>
        <SubstanceForm addSubstanceToHistory={addSubstanceToHistory} newSubstance={newSubstance} setNewSubstance={setNewSubstance} />  
        <PreviousSearches substances={substances} deleteSubstance={deleteSubstance} setNewSubstance={setNewSubstance} />
    </>
)

Inside the SubstanceForm component the form has an onSubmit property.
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}> ... </form>

The code for async function handleSubmit() lives inside the SubstanceForm component. This is responsible for submitting the CAS to the API, rendering results, and handing errors (e.g. API request failed) - all of which works.
I don't want to move handleSubmit() into the parent App.jsx because it would require a lot of other changes to render SubstanceForm which is currently otherwise working fine.
Following the linked SO answer I've tried this. Inside <PreviousSearches> I have:
export function PreviousSearches({ substances, setNewSubstance //... other props here }) {

substances comes from Local Storage via App.jsx. I am rendering out each CAS (as per screenshot) and have an onClick for each one.
{substances.map(substance => {
  return (
    <li key={substance.id}>
      <a href="#" onClick={(e) => reRunSearch(e, substance.title) }>{substance.title}</a>
    </li>
  )
})}

Because reRunSearch() lives inside the PreviousSearches component I am able to repopulate the search form - even though that's inside SubstancesForm - like this:
function reRunSearch(e, cas) {
  e.preventDefault()
  setNewSubstance(cas)
}

The cas value gets passed via App.jsx into the SubstanceForm component via the props.
My assumption was I could pass something else from PreviousSearches into SubstanceForm. I added the following to App.jsx:
export default function App() {
    const [externalFormSubmit, setExternalFormSubmit] = useState(false)
}

I passed this into SubstancesForm via a new prop.
<SubstanceForm externalFormSubmit={externalFormSubmit} />

If I console.log(externalFormSubmit) inside SubstanceForm it does indeed log false. I need to be able to update that value from the PreviousSearches component so I created a function in App.jsx that allows it. value here is boolean.
function updateExternalFormSubmit(value) {
  setExternalFormSubmit(value)
}

In PreviousSearches I can call that function when about to re-run the search:
function reRunSearch(e, cas) {
  // ...
  setNewSubstance(cas)
  updateExternalFormSubmit(true) // <- ADDED THIS
}

The problem
It does console.log(true) so I can see it's been updated. If I then try and use that to re-run the search
// inside SearchForm.jsx
if (externalFormSubmit) {
  updateExternalFormSubmit(false)
  handleSubmit()
}

There is an error in the console

Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

It seems to send >50 requests to the API. It does actually render results in the UI eventually but there is a lag of 1-2 seconds.
Common sense is telling me this is wrong. All the answers I've looked at to do with how to submit a form in React via another component go along the lines of "lift up state" and notify the child component via the parent. Since that is what I'm doing I don't know how to fix this.
Any advice would be appreciated.

Can you provide more code from your form component? in here: if (externalFormSubmit) {
updateExternalFormSubmit(false)
handleSubmit()
} do you have any useEffect that runs this code?

The only part of the code which uses useEffect is the feature that loads search history (Previous Searches) from Local Storage. That works and has done since the early days of the app being built.

@jam Please do not add deprecated tags [tag:api] to posts

@BrianTompsett-汤莱恩 thank you for your feedback

The problem is that you are using this block of code:
 if (externalFormSubmit) {
  updateExternalFormSubmit(false)
  handleSubmit()
}

outside a useEffect hook and that's why every time that a state or prop updates on your form component this block of code runs and because it also updates a state inside it your component will go on a loop as it updates the state and rerender everytime.
What you should do is to wrap this inside a useEffect to ensure that it does not run every time the component rerenders:
useEffect(() => {
  if (externalFormSubmit) {
    updateExternalFormSubmit(false);
    handleSubmit();
  }
}, [newSubstance]);

This makes sure that only if there is a newSubstance there run this if block and handleSubmit if externalFormSubmit is true.
More info on useEffect hook: https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect

Thanks I'll give this a go. Does this seem a resonable way of submitting the form? Whenever I've looked up this topic about how to resubmit a form in React it seems extremely convoluted, especially given the app already has a function to do just that? The issue seems that child components can't speak to each other directly so I can't call handleSubmit() from PreviousSearches even though handleSubmit() is exactly what I want to run.

Yeah passing states and communication between states are complicated a bit and this is why we have react context and state management libraries like redux to do it on more complex situation to prevent prop drilling and other issues.

This works, thank you so much.

I'm happy that I could help

I don't know how does your app works but If you want to submit the form using a button from another component you can also pass a form attribute to that button and pass the same id as your form and it will submit the form without all these problems: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_form.asp

I think there is a structural issue. You should place your "handleDataChange" function and shared data in your parent component (in this case, App.jsx). Otherwise, if you prefer not to share the data through the parent component, you could use React Context instead.
Here is a link to documentation about context
https://react.dev/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context

I'd said in the question "I don't want to move handleSubmit() into the parent App.jsx because it would require a lot of other changes". Basically this problem comes down to whether I can call the handleSubmit() function which lives in SubstanceForm component from another component, in this case PreviousSearches.
